# postgresql - sql - count of `true` values

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
myCol
------
 true
 true
 true
 false
 false
 null
```

In the above table, if I do :

```
select count(*), count(myCol);
```

I get `6, 5`

I get `5` as it doesn't count the null entry.

How do I also count the number of true values (3 in the example)?

(This is a simplification and I'm actually using a much more complicated expression within the count function)

Edit summary: I also want to include a plain count(*) in the query, so can't use a where clause

Comment: Does 't' stand for True anf 'f' for False? Or are you looking for something like SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myCol).

Comment: take a look at my second example, you can throw a `WHERE myCol = true` in there if you want and if you remove the first `*,` it'll just return the number.

Comment: @Shamit yes t stands for true, and f stands for false, I've updated the question

Comment: You might as well not simplify your question/query... your requirements restrict the better performance possibilities and people are responding with inefficient answers, which are getting bumped up for no good reason.

Comment: @vol7ron in my defense there has to be some simplification in order to ask a comprehensible question, but yes, I oversimplified when I originally posted.

Comment: @EgohanM: =] I do it all the time, but when you start saying "can't use `where`" your simplification is not exact.  Besides, if you're using a subquery anyhow, you can use a WHERE.  The better thing to do would be to use a `join`

Comment: The new `filter` approach from [Ilja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334318/918959) should be more widely known

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(CASE WHEN myCol THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) FROM <table name>
```

or, as you found out for yourself:

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN myCol THEN 1 END) FROM <table name>
```

Comment: also, any reason why you did sum(.. THEN 1 ELSE 0) instead of count(.. THEN true else null) ?

Comment: No... it is just that I wasn't sure which values would count() count... and I knew that sum did the trick. But beware: On second thought I believe that sum() over only null values will return null, so it should be COALESCE(sum(...),0) for you, or, in other words, count() is better,

Comment: Thankyou! Never thought my query would work in a million years!

Comment: @EoghanM, see shorter answer involving cast.

Comment: You can actually omit `ELSE null` to get the same result.

Comment: @200_success: +1 Correct! Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also use COUNT() to do more esoteric applications like `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN mycol2 THEN mycol1 END)` which counts distinct mycol1 when mycol2 is true

Comment: if you don't put "else 0" and there is no values matching that criteria, you get null from count

Answer (score 159):

Since PostgreSQL 9.4 there's the [`FILTER` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), which allows for a very concise query to count the true values:

```
select count(*) filter (where myCol)
from tbl;
```

The above query is a bad example in that a simple WHERE clause would suffice, and is for demonstrating the syntax only. Where the FILTER clause shines is that it is easy to combine with other aggregates:

```
select count(*), -- all
       count(myCol), -- non null
       count(*) filter (where myCol) -- true
from tbl;
```

The clause is especially handy for aggregates on a column that uses another column as the predicate, while allowing to fetch differently filtered aggregates in a single query:

```
select count(*),
       sum(otherCol) filter (where myCol)
from tbl;
```

Answer (score 118):

Cast the Boolean to an integer and sum.

```
SELECT count(*),sum(myCol::int);
```

You get `6,3`.

Comment: Plus1: Nice hack! This is probably even faster than my solution.

Comment: This is the best and shortest solution (and has equivalences in many other programming environments and software). Should be up-voted more

Comment: The 'cast to int and count' is clearly the most concise, but that doesn't make it best. I would not endorse this, because while many environments use the 0/1 representation for false/true, many use 0/non-zero, including -1.  I agree it's a "hack," and casts are dicey enough when they aren't "hacks."  Won't downvote but again, wouldn't endorse.

Answer (score 48):

probably, the best approach is to use nullif function.

in general

```
select
    count(nullif(myCol = false, true)),  -- count true values
    count(nullif(myCol = true, true)),   -- count false values
    count(myCol);
```

or in short

```
select
    count(nullif(myCol, true)),  -- count false values
    count(nullif(myCol, false)), -- count true values
    count(myCol);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: Your "in general" looks wrong: AFAICS, `nullif([boolean expression], true)` will return `false` if [boolean expression] is false, and `null` if it is true, so you will be counting the false values. I think you want `nullif([boolean expression], false)`.

Comment: yep, the "general" case should be the other way around. fixed. thanks.

Comment: Yuk. That fix is really confusing. AFAICS, it will now count true or null values.  I think that rephrasing it so that you always have `nullif([boolean expression], false)` makes it much easier to read. You can then vary the boolean expression part to be whatever you like, in this case `myCol = true` to count true values, or `myCol = false` to count false values, or `name='john'` to count people called john etc.

Answer (score 29):

The shortest and laziest (without casting) solution would be to use the formula:

```
SELECT COUNT(myCol OR NULL) FROM myTable;
```

Try it yourself:

```
SELECT COUNT(x < 7 OR NULL)
   FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,10) t(x);
```

gives the same result than

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN x < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,10) t(x);
```

Comment: This is definitely a nicer solution than mine :)

Comment: Very insightful answer.

Answer (score 10):

Simply convert boolean field to integer and do a sum. This will work on postgresql :

```
select sum(myCol::int) from <table name>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It is neither faster nor more precise than the other solutions. I believe you come from Oracle when using ints as boolean is more intuitive for you.

Comment: While it won't work for NULL, its perfect if it is boolean and NOT NULL - was very useful for my case, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
select f1,
       CASE WHEN f1 = 't' THEN COUNT(*) 
            WHEN f1 = 'f' THEN COUNT(*) 
            END AS counts,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) AS total_counts
from mytable
group by f1
```

Or Maybe this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN f1 = 't' THEN 1 END) AS t,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f1 = 'f' THEN 1 END) AS f,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f1 NOT IN ('t','f') OR f1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS others,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f1 IS NOT NULL OR f1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_count
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: +1 If `myCol` expression is a boolean, you can replace the check with `where (myCol)`

Comment: sorry I oversimplified my example: I can't use a where clause as I also want to return a total count representing the total number of rows, as well as a count of the true values.

Answer (score 8):

In MySQL, you can do this as well:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total
     , sum(myCol) AS countTrue --yes, you can add TRUEs as TRUE=1 and FALSE=0 !!
FROM yourTable
;
```

I think that in Postgres, this works:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total
     , sum(myCol::int) AS countTrue --convert Boolean to Integer
FROM yourTable
;
```

or better (to avoid :: and use standard SQL syntax):

```
SELECT count(*) AS total
     , sum(CAST(myCol AS int)) AS countTrue --convert Boolean to Integer
FROM yourTable
;
```

Comment: This is the most simple solution I have ever seen ^_^

Answer (score 5):

## Benchmark

**TL;DR:** take the solution you like. There's no significant difference.

### Utility scripts

```sh
before(){
    psql <<-SQL
        create table bench (
                id         serial
            , thebool    boolean
        );

        insert into bench (thebool)
        select (random() > 0.5)
        from generate_series(1, 1e6) g;


        analyze bench;
    SQL
}
after(){
    psql -c 'drop table bench'
}
test(){
    echo $(tput bold)$1$(tput sgr0)
    psql -c "explain analyze select $1 from bench" | tail -4 | head -2
}
```

### Actual benchmark

Made on a 1.4GHz i5 MacBookPro, psql and pg 12.4 (pg in a linux docker container):

```sh
before  
test 'count(*) filter (where thebool)'
# Planning Time: 0.138 ms
# Execution Time: 4424.042 ms
test 'count(case when thebool then 1 end)'
# Planning Time: 0.156 ms
# Execution Time: 4638.861 ms
test 'count(nullif(thebool, false))'
# Planning Time: 0.201 ms
# Execution Time: 5267.631 ms
test 'count(thebool or null)'
# Planning Time: 0.202 ms
# Execution Time: 4672.700 ms
test 'sum(thebool::integer)'
# Planning Time: 0.155 ms
# Execution Time: 4602.406 ms
test 'coalesce(sum(case when thebool THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)'
# Planning Time: 0.167 ms
# Execution Time: 4416.503 ms
after
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT count(*)         -- or count(myCol)
FROM   <table name>     -- replace <table name> with your table
WHERE  myCol = true;
```

Here's a way with Windowing Function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, count(*) over(partition by myCol)
FROM   <table name>;

-- Outputs:
-- --------------
-- myCol | count
-- ------+-------
--  f    |  2
--  t    |  3
--       |  1
```

Comment: sorry I can't return multiple rows for the more complicated example I'm applying this solution to.

Comment: Yes, but you can restrict it further by just adding `WHERE myCol = true`.  I provided the second example not because it's any faster, but more as an educational piece to Postgres's windowing functions, which many users aren't comfortable with, or don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(myCol)
from mytable
group by myCol
;
```

will group the 3 possible states of bool (false, true, 0) in three rows
especially handy when grouping together with another column like day