# SQL counting unique true values on join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, aggregate-functions

I have a `users` table

```
Table "public.users"
Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
user_id | integer | 
style   | boolean | 
id      | integer |
```

and an `access_rights` table

```
Table "public.access_rights"
Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
user_id | integer | 
id      | integer |
```

I have a query joining users on access right and I want to count the number of values in the style column that are true.

From this answer: [postgresql - sql - count of `true` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396498/postgresql-sql-count-of-true-values), I tried doing

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN style THEN 1 ELSE null END )
from users
join access_rights on access_rights.user_id = users.user_id
;
```

But that counts duplicate values when a user has multiple rows for access_rights. How can I count values only once when using a join?

Comment: why don't you first filter by the value and then count the rows? you will need to add a where clause to your query `where style = 1 OR NULL`, that will return only rows with style value equal to true and then you can count the rows.

Comment: if you have two records with `user_id = 1, style = TRUE` in users and three records with `user_id = 1` in access_rights, what do you expect to return? 1, 2, 3, or 6?

Comment: This is a contrived example but the user_id column can be considered a primary key so that wouldn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the number of users that have *at least* 1 row with (`style IS TRUE`) in `access_rights`, aggregate `access_rights` before you join:

```
SELECT count(style OR NULL) AS style_ct
FROM   users
JOIN  (
   SELECT user_id, bool_or(style) AS style
   FROM   access_rights
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) u USING (user_id);
```

Using `JOIN`, since users without any entries in `access_rights` don't count in this case.
Using the aggregate function [`bool_or()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

**Or** even simpler:

```
SELECT count(*) AS style_ct
FROM   (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM   access_rights
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING bool_or(style)
   );
```

This is assuming a foreign key enforcing referential integrity, so there is no `access_rights.user_id` without a corresponding row in `users`.
Also assuming no `NULL` values in `access_rights.user_id`, which would increase the count by 1 - and can be countered by using `count(user_id)` instead of `count(*)`.

**Or** (if that assumption is not true) use an `EXISTS` semi-join:

```
SELECT count( EXISTS (
              SELECT  1
              FROM    access_rights
              WHERE   user_id = u.user_id
              AND     style  -- boolean value evaluates on its own
              ) OR NULL
            )
FROM   users u;
```

I am using the capabilities of true `boolean` values to simplify the count and the `WHERE` clause. Details:
[Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, you always come through with some good answers I appreciate it!

Comment: @jvans: Good to hear. :) Consider the even simpler variant I added.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

Try something like this (per [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/datatype-boolean.html))

```
select sum( case style when TRUE then 1 else 0 end ) as style_count
from public.users         u
join public.access_rights ar on ar.user_id = u.user_id
```

Or, considering your problem statement, "*I want to count the number of values in the style column that are true*", you could do this:

```
select count(*) as style_count
from public.users         u
join public.access_rights ar on ar.user_id = u.user_id
where u.style = TRUE
```

**Edited To Note:**

On re-reading your question, it sounds like what you really want is a count of distinct users whose `style` attribute is `true`, and who have an access right. You can get to that by this:

```
select count(distinct u.user_id)
from public.users u
join public.access_rights ar on ar.user_id = u.user_id
where u.style = TRUE
;
```

Another way to get there would be like this:

```
select count(*)
from public.users u
where u.style = TRUE
  and exists ( select *
               from public.access_rights ar
               where ar.user_id = u.user_id
             )
```

I would vote for the latter as it more clearly shows your intent.

Answer (score 1):

It seems each one has a different understanding of the question. Here is mine

```
select
    count(case when style then 1 end) as classic_case,
    count(style or null) as boolean_count
from users u
where exists (
    select 1
    from access_rights
    where user_id = u.user_id
)
```

It will count the total number of trues for users which have access_rights.