# Can I use aggregate expressions using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, aggregate-functions

PostgreSQL have [aggregate expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), e.g. `count(*) FILTER (WHERE state = 'success')`.  How can I generate such expressions using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Completely different topic. That's about aggregate functions, and this is about aggregate expressions.

Comment: I'd not go so far as to say completely different, but here's a better dupe candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167101/sqlalchemy-count-status-is-true, also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328779/sqlalchemy-func-count-on-boolean-column/37333820). The relevant documentation: [`funcfilter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.funcfilter) and [`FunctionElement.filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.filter).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose I have a model `Machine` with a boolean field `active`, and would like to filter the count by `active = true`

### Using [`func.count(...).filter(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.filter)

```
from models import db, Machine
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

query = db.session.query(
    func.count(Machine.id).filter(Machine.active == True)
    .label('active_machines')
)
```

We can look at the generated SQL query:

```
>>> print(query)
SELECT count(machine.id) FILTER (WHERE machine.active = true) AS active_machines 
FROM machine
```

This should work the same for the other aggregate functions like `func.avg`, `func.sum`, etc

### Longer syntax using `funcfilter(count(...), filter)`

`func.count(Machine.id).filter(Machine.active == True)` is short hand for:

```
from sqlalchemy import funcfilter

funcfilter(func.count(Machine.id), Machine.active == True)
```