# How can i make a count with different filters in SQLAlchemy - Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The main problem is to count different elements with Sqlalchemy at the same time. I want to achieve the following SQL.

```
SELECT
        metrics_stages.job_id,
        COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE metrics_stages.stage = 'Submitted') AS submitted_count,
        COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE metrics_stages.stage = 'Applied') AS applied_count,
        COUNT(distinct metrics_stages.talents_job_id) FILTER(WHERE metrics_stages.if_interview = true) AS interview_count
    FROM metrics_stages
    GROUP BY metrics_stages.job_id
```

But i can not make it possible.

Comment: Why don't you try something like SUM(IF(stage = 'Submtted',1,0)) as submitted_count

Comment: Why can you not make it possible? Should be just `func.count().filter(...)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328779/sqlalchemy-func-count-on-boolean-column/37333891#37333891

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what database you are using, in MariaDB and MySQL you can do it like this.

```
SELECT
    metrics_stages.job_id,
    SUM(IF(metrics_stages.stage = 'Submitted',1,0)) AS submitted_count,
    SUM(IF(metrics_stages.stage = 'Applied',1,0)) AS applied_count,       
    COUNT(distinct IF(metrics_stages.if_interviewed = true, metrics_stages.talents_job_id, NULL)) AS interview_count
FROM metrics_stages
GROUP BY metrics_stages.job_id
```