# SQLAlchemy analog of Posgresql FILTER

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to convert this query to SQLAlchemy

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER(where condition) as cnt FROM table
```

Can someone give me minimal example of this? Can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_10.html#feature-gh134) what you want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328779/sqlalchemy-func-count-on-boolean-column has an example of using `FILTER` with SQLA.