# SQLAlchemy return only groups that follow some condition for all grouped rows in a group_by

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

Let's say I have two tables, `A` and `B`:

```
class Status(Enum):
    COMPLETED = "COMPLETED"
    FAILED = "FAILED"

class A(Base):
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Enum(Status), index=True)

class B(Base):
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('A.id'), index=True)
    group_column = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

I want to build a filter that will join those two tables via `a_id` and group the results by `group_column`, but will check that, within each grouping, all grouped rows have `status == Status.FAILED`.

One way I was thinking to do this would be to use the `having` function and try to filter by counting all rows and comparing with the rows that contain the expected state, so something like:

```
db.query(B)
    .join(A)
    .group_by(A.group_column)
    .having(database.func.count('*') ==
            database.func.count(B.sync_state == Status.FAILED))
```

However I am not sure how to get `database.func.count` to count based on a condition, or if that's even possible. Is there some way to fix this query or do I have to try a different approach entirely?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328779/sqlalchemy-func-count-on-boolean-column/37333891#37333891, but you can also do it directly in PostgreSQL using `bool_and()` aggregate.

Comment: It worked this way, thanks!