# Include rows in ResultSet but exclude from LIMIT

Tags: postgresql

How do I `SELECT` rows using a `LIMIT` but exclude rows from that `LIMIT` which have a value for the column `disabled` = true.

**Disabled rows should also be returned in the result set but not increment `LIMIT` when they're identified.**

For example: 
Given table `Runners`

```
id   runner   km_run   disabled
 1     mary      3.5       true
 2     anna      1.5      false
 3     john      6.5      false
 4     bill      1.5      false
 5     jess      6.2       true
 6     jack      2.5      false
```

How would I do something like:

`SELECT * FROM runners LIMIT 4` so that it returns every row above?

I considered using a [dynamic LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910044) like this:

`SELECT * FROM runners LIMIT (4+sum(disabled::int))` but this counts **every** disabled entry in the table as opposed to the ones iterated over so far. It also produces this error:

> aggregate functions are not allowed in LIMIT

The table `runners` is 100,000+ rows and 65 columns. What's a more efficient approach?

**Setup Queries:**

```
CREATE TABLE runners(
 id SERIAL,
 runner VARCHAR, 
 km_run DECIMAL,
 disabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, disabled)
VALUES ('mary', 3.5, true);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, disabled)
VALUES ('anna', 1.5, false);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, disabled)
VALUES ('john', 6.5, false);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, disabled)
VALUES ('bill', 1.5, false);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, disabled)
VALUES ('jess', 6.2, true);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, disabled)
VALUES ('jack', 2.5, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must get the maximum `id` for the rows having `disabled = false` and then `select` at least up to that `id`:

```
select * from runners
where id <= (
  select coalesce(min(r.id), 4) 
  from runners r
  where (select count(*) from runners where id <= r.id and disabled = false) = 4
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=4f611db0ba009b334c1c70c91c78bad7).
Results:

```
> id | runner | km_run | disabled
> -: | :----- | -----: | :-------
>  1 | mary   |    3.5 | t       
>  2 | anna   |    1.5 | f       
>  3 | john   |    6.5 | f       
>  4 | bill   |    1.5 | f       
>  5 | jess   |    6.2 | t       
>  6 | jack   |    2.5 | f
```

Comment: That certainly works, thank you. Would you consider this an efficient query, given the size of my table? I'm wondering if I should re-think my approach or is this not completely insane?

Comment: I really can't tell about the efficiency if you have a large table, you must test it.

Comment: Fair enough, appreciate your time.