# How to retrieve the percentage share of a dimension

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve the country with the second highest percentage of female workers from my dataset.

Theses are the dimensions that are relevant from the table:

Table name is "employee"
country(varchar)
male(boolean)
female(boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the database. Assuming you're using MySQL (most used DB) boolean is an equivalent to tinyint(1). This makes integer arithmetics without casting or if then else logic possible:

```
SELECT country, (sum(male)/ sum(female)) as ratio FROM employee GROUP BY country order by ratio desc limit 2;
```

Then pick 2nd result (or use Limit 1, 1 if you're really not interested in the highest value).

If you need to cast as you're using PostGres you can have a look here:
[postgresql - sql - count of 'true' values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396498/postgresql-sql-count-of-true-values)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Country
FROM employee
GROUP BY Country -- get aggregate per Country
ORDER BY SUM(Female) / SUM(Male) DESC -- Higher percentage goes up
LIMIT 1, 1 -- after 1st, next 1 row(s)
;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.