# How to write SQL query with multiple conditions using CASE function

Tags: postgresql, multiple-conditions

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rdDl.png)
The task is:
Count the number of customers who simultaneously:

1. have more than 5 payments that exeed 5000 dollars
2. and have an average payment value of more than 10,000 dollars

I have done it using window function and subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
client INT,
payment INT);

INSERT INTO Customers(client, payment) VALUES
(1, 1000),
(1, 7000),
(1, 6000),
(1, 50000),
(1, 5500),
(1, 5600),
(2, 1000),
(2, 1000);

select client, count(payment) from
(select *, avg(payment) over(partition by client) as avg_payment from Customers) as t1
where payment > 5000
group by client
having count(payment)>5
```

But I have to make it without window function and subquery. I've been told it is possible to do it only with the use of CASE function. I'll be happy if someone could help me optimize my query.

Comment: You are missing the `avg_payment > 10_000` condition?

Comment: Notice that for your example table, the expected result *is* empty, since client `1` has exactly 5 payments exceeding 5000$, not more than 5 payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Working fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T50gHyKL)

Let's break the query down into pieces:

1. Find customers who have more than 5 payments that exceed 5000 dollars

You can query for payments more then $5,000 in your `WHERE` clause, and then specify the "more than 5 payments" in your `HAVING` clause (after aggregating by Client ID):

```
SELECT 
  client, 
  COUNT(*) AS payment_gt_5000
FROM customers
WHERE payment > 5000
GROUP BY client
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

(note that I changed `>5` to `>=5`, since Client ID 1 has exactly 5 matching payments).

Then if we wanted to capture "average payment value of more than 10,000 dollars", we'd use a very similar query:

```
SELECT 
  client, 
  AVG(payment)
FROM customers
GROUP BY client
HAVING AVG(payment) > 10000
```

Since these 2 queries are very similar, we should be able to combine them. The only tricky part is we have to get rid of the `payment > 5000` from the `WHERE` clause, since we want to calculate averages for *all* payments. But wait…it's a bird! It's a plane! It's conditional aggregation to the rescue:

```
SELECT 
  client, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN payment > 5000 THEN 1 END) AS payment_gt_5000,
  AVG(payment) AS avg_payment
FROM customers
GROUP BY client
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN payment > 5000 THEN 1 END) >= 5
    AND AVG(payment) > 10000
```

We're not applying the `payment > 5000` to the `WHERE` clause, so we're getting the average for all payments like we want. But we're still getting the count of payments > 5000 (`COUNT(CASE WHEN payment > 5000 THEN 1 END)`), so we can still figure out in the `HAVING` clause which clients have 5+ payments of more than $5,000.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the subquery by placing the aggregation directly in the `having` clause:

```
select client
from Customers
group by client
having count(*) filter(where payment > 5000) > 5
   and avg(payment) > 10000
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9zHiuz0N))</sup>

<sub>I prefer `count(*)` over `count(payment)` since the latter does not count rows with a `NULL` value, though it doesn't matter here due to the `> 5000` condition.</sub>

Now instead of using `filter`, you can use a `sum` that conditionally counts either `1` or `0` per row, and use a `CASE` statement for that:

```
…
having sum(case when payment > 5000 then 1 else 0 end) > 5
```

or

```
…
having count(case when payment > 5000 then 1 /* else null */ end) > 5
```

or

```
…
having sum((payment > 5000)::int) > 5
```

though using `filter` is much more elegant and straightforward. See also [postgresql - sql - count of `true` values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5396498/1048572).

Comment: Can’t suggest edit, should this be select count(distinct client)….?

Comment: @Stickleback Not necessary with `group by client`

Comment: thanks. For my understanding will this return a client ‘id’ list vs count of client?

Comment: @Stickleback Yes indeed. I don't how how to return a single count without a subquery or CTE

Comment: @Stickleback I see now what you meant, but [`count(distinct client)` does not work](https://dbfiddle.uk/u2oFfHFg), as it still does `group by client` so it always returns 1.

Comment: But the grouping variable is not in the selection does this matter? Sorry my back ground is sas and it’s quirky in its sql implementation.

Comment: @Stickleback no, that does not matter. Any aggregate (such as `count`) is grouped by the `group by` expression(s), regardless whether those expression are also selected themselves or not. The overall count [would require a subquery or CTE](https://dbfiddle.uk/fCMgIqBg)

Comment: True, thanks @Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, based on the question ‘Count the number of customers....’ there isn’t a way of doing this using a single select statement without a join.

It would require either a window function or CTE or subquery to return the aggregation. This is because you cannot run two different groupings within the same selection without a window function (which is required for the initial average and then to count the client IDs)